# Can riding a bicycle increase stamina?

Tags: exercise, stamina

As in our daily busy life we have to do some exercise to make our self fit and fine .Me as a student and also a working women surely needs a lot of exercise. I'm found of riding bicycle but it tired me up so much but on the other i have to know that riding a bicycle really cheer you up and increase your stamina.Please guide me in best way so that i that i continue my exercise.

Comment: It is a known fact that exercises helps us to gain physical strength, stamina and GOOD MOOD. As you are a student + working women I believe you should do exercise of any kind not cycling only. you can do rope skipping, squats etc indoor exercises if you always don't get time to cycle.
I would suggest mixing of indoor exercises and cycling (to office / work) as you will have variety in exercises and health together with following your hobbie.

Comment: I think it is more about the time actually. 5 minutes of cycling won't increase your stamina, but gradually increasing (cycling for longer periods) will.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can definitely. It's an endurance sport, from which top athletes are known for having extremely low resting heart rates, due to the strenghtening of their cardiac muscles, and lungs :
https://www.cyclingweekly.com/fitness/miguel-indurain-vs-your-body-34288

Also, women who does endurance sports like biking or running tend to have nice legs ;)

Keep in mind that in any sport, you have to rest enough and eat accordingly to recover and be able to progress.